# why my h1 element appear behind header-image though it is defined below header element?

Tags: html, css

Why is my h1 element appearing behind header-image though it is defined below header element?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 60vw;
}

#header-img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="logo"><img id="header-img" src="https://s8.postimg.cc/kxr6hl1v9/logo.png"></img>
  </div>
</header>

<div>
  <h1>hello i'm vivek dalsaniya</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<header>` is `position: fixed`. Any element that is not `position: static` (the default) or `position: relative` is taken out of [normal flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) and doesn't influence the layout of elements that are not its descendants.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to the `display: fixed`. Removing it solves the issue

```css
header{
  display:flex;
  height:75px;
  width:100%;
}

.logo{
  width:60vw;
}

#header-img{
  width:auto;
  height:100%;
}

nav{
  margin:20px;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  padding:0px 10px;
 
}

li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
   <div class="logo">
     <img id="header-img" src="https://app.mangoconnects.com/assets/mango_logo_2f-b45e222cecb567cb52fe084150e627c2c0ed3b62b453bf4f68f46aa0f8a40dd7.png">      </img>
    </div> 
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="">
     <ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#product">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <ul>  
  </nav>
 </header>
 
 <div id="about">
   <h1>Who we are</h1>
    </div>
 <div id="product"></div>   
 <div id="contact"></div>
```

Comment: if i want my header element to remain fixed at top then?what are other possible solution?

Comment: Don't put any other element before it, so that it follows the page flow.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use position fixed and The element is positioned relative to the browser window.

Comment: if i want my header element to remain fixed at top then?what are other possible solution?

Comment: I don't know what do want to do exactly, for example if you want a fixed header at the top of page you can position it as sticky and ...

Answer (score -1):

Give your div that is holding the H1 a padding to offset your header.

```
<div style="padding-top:80px;">
  <h1>hello i'm vivek dalsaniya</h1>
</div>
```